# Multiple instances of iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is it possible to have more than one iPhone Simulator Application running at the same time ? I would love to be able to do so because I'm working with some networking applications and it's really painful to deploy every single time I want to test stuff... this could be a huge time saver for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to report that as of Xcode 9 we now support multiple Simulators running concurrently.

Use the Hardware, Device menu or `xcrun simctl boot` to start multiple devices simultaneously.